# Convert js project to NME project?

Tags: haxe, createjs, nme

I have a project written in createJS using haxe js project, what would it involve to re-write the project to be NME based targeting AS3?

Is it a difficult task? any one tried this before?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Okey, after one months, no answers! so, I decided to answer my question, as I have already started porting my createJS project to haxe nme, here is what I got:

- haxe nme is now openFL
- targeting flash with openFL is very easy! they are using the same Flash APIs
- using FlashDevelop, you will need to use conditional compilation
- to keep things simple, rather than re-writing onPress, onMouseMove .. etc in createJS, I've created a wraper classes that use the same APIs of createJS, which will add events/ remove events behind the scenes
- also, I wrote a wrapper for Tween to use Actuate behind the scenes.

Any one needs those wrappers, I would be glad to help!